# php set username and password

Tags: php, html

I've been trying to set up a login system, but can't set my username and password.

```
<?php
session_start();
$user = “u1”;
$password = “p1”;
if ($_POST[‘username’] == $user ) &&
    ($_POST[‘password’] == $password) {
    echo welcome.php;
}
else echo you have entered the wrong credentials.
?>
```

Comment: How can code work? No ' or " on echo, and some strange double quotes on strings...

Comment: your form should have it's method attribute equal to POST like this 
`<form method="post"/>`

Comment: It should be `if(($_POST[‘username’] == $user) && ($_POST[‘password’] == $password))`
You ate a bracket!

Comment: you succeed logging in but do not succeed in keeping the login status?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND in ...

Comment: stop using word, or what ever crazy editor you have chosen, that gives non standard quotes

Comment: ONE of the issues with your code are the curly quotes `“ ”` and `‘ ’` --- Those will break "any" code whether the conditions are right or not. Use `"` and `'` respectively.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me. I've learned something new today!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is only for illustrative purposes and to answer this question, but understand this is not a secure system and should not be used ANYWHERE *EVER* near a production environment!**

I think it might be an issue with how you've set up your `if` and `else` statements, as well as you having a syntax error with the `echo` statement. Try something like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$user = 'u1';
$password = 'p1';
if ($_POST['username'] == $user  && $_POST['password'] == $password) {
  echo 'successfully logged in'; // changed to just show successful message
} else {
  echo 'you have entered the wrong credentials.'; // Placed quotes around echo statement
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Oops, sorry, I missed a semi colon, try my code now.

Comment: Also please read the comments in your original question, especially about the quotes - one of the issues in your original code was your quotes were malformed and probably from the program you used. Use a different program to edit your PHP code like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be quotation and bracket problem. This should hopefully work for you:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $user = "u1";
    $password = "p1";
    if (($_POST['username'] == $user ) && ($_POST['password'] == $password)) {
        echo welcome.php;
    }
    else echo "you have entered the wrong credentials".
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if ($_POST[‘username’] == $user ) && ($_POST[‘password’] == $password) {
```

with

```
if (($_POST[‘username’] == $user ) && ($_POST[‘password’] == $password)) {
```